# Triominos “take from the well” rules

Tags: triominos

At Triominos, when you decide to take from the well; but you have a tile that fits on your board, can you decide to use the tile that you already had and therefore skip the second (-5) and third (-5) time to pick from the well including the extra minus points (-10)  as punishment if you cannot place your third pick from the well?

Answer (score 1):

You have play the triomino that you bought, you **can't** use the triomino that you already had.

From the [rules](https://www.kookaburra.com.au/documents/instructions/ZCW4451_11.pdf):

> YOU HAVE NOT PUT DOWN A TRI-OMINO?
>
> If you cannot or do not want to put down a matching Tri-omino, you MUST 'buy' a Tri-omino. You may then **play this 'bought' tile in the same turn**. <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>